# How to understand "pre" in Preintegration of IMU?

Tags: computer-vision, robotics, slam

I see *preintegration* in IMU-fused SLAM literatures, which mention that *preintegration is useful in avoiding to recompute the IMU integration between two consecutive keyframes*.

However, when I see some open-sourced SLAM code, e.g. OrbSLAM3, I haven't found anything special in preintegration because it just looks like an ordinary integration (with same time-intervals, same interpolation, same full caculation over multiple intervals), and I don't see an expected pre-calculated value that is reused time and time again.

So my question, is *preintegration* just an alias of the integration of IMU, or else how to correctly understand "**pre**"?

Comment: This question is not related to programming. Maybe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ would be suitable? I don’t know.

Comment: @CrisLuengo These two sites are with potential value, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've made clear of ***Preintegration***.

It is a misunderstanding to think of *Preintegration* as a pre-calculated value that is reusable in each process for calculating any new integration.

**In fact**, *Preintegration* actually means that people **temporarily** calculate integrations **in a rough way** for incoming any time instant (say, instant *0, 1, 2, ..., k-1*) and, at a key instant *k*, a bundle adjustment can be performed on the *pre-integrations* over time instants [*0, k*] **without recomputing** the integration on time instant *0, 1, 2, ..., k-1*.